# "which" function inside a custom function to find a column number basis some condition

Tags: r, custom-function

I am preparing a function to locate the column number in one data refering the name from other dataset

I have 2 datasets test 1 and test2, I am preparing a function to find column name from test1 in the other dataset test 2(column number).

> dput(test1)

```
structure(list(mastercode_02 = c(3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L, 
3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L), mastercode_03 = c(3039617L, 3039617L, 
3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L), mastercode_04 = c(3000470L, 
3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L), mastercode_05 = c(3039123L, 
3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L), mastercode_06 = c(1000054L, 
1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L), mastercode_07 = 1000001:1000006, 
    mastercode_08 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_09 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), mastercode_10 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_11 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), mastercode_12 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x07fb2498>)
```

second data

Console~/

> dput(test2)

```
structure(list(QID_121 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), QID_131 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), unitlevel = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), mastercode_01 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), mastercode_02 = c(3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L, 
3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L), mastercode_03 = c(3039617L, 3039617L, 
3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L), mastercode_04 = c(3000470L, 
3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L), mastercode_05 = c(3039123L, 
3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L), mastercode_06 = c(1000054L, 
1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L), mastercode_07 = 1000001:1000006, 
    mastercode_08 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_09 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), mastercode_10 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_11 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), mastercode_12 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x07fb2498>)
```

I want something like below, which can be used within another functions:

```
levelfun<-function(m,dataset){

levelname<-names(mastercodes)[[m]]

level_filter_data<-dataset%>% filter(unitlevel>m)

k=which(names(level_filter_data)==levelname)}
```

here I am getting error with the last line, may be I should use alternate to which function.

Comment: .  What is `mastercodes` inside the function?  Also, there is `dataset` that is not a parameter to the function

Comment: If you want to find an index base don column names, use `match` `match(names(test1), names(test2))`

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is a little unclear, but using your example to create test1 and test2 data frames:

```
test1<-structure(list(mastercode_02 = c(3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L, 
                                 3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L), mastercode_03 = c(3039617L, 3039617L, 
                                                                                  3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L), mastercode_04 = c(3000470L, 
                                                                                                                                             3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L), mastercode_05 = c(3039123L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L), mastercode_06 = c(1000054L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L), mastercode_07 = 1000001:1000006, 
               mastercode_08 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                 NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_09 = c(NA_integer_, 
                                                                                           NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
                                 ), mastercode_10 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                                      NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_11 = c(NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
                                                      ), mastercode_12 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                                                           NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                              "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

test2<-structure(list(QID_121 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                              NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), QID_131 = c(NA_integer_, 
                                                                                  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
                              ), unitlevel = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), mastercode_01 = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                    NA, NA, NA, NA), mastercode_02 = c(3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L, 
                                                                                                                       3036696L, 3036696L, 3036696L), mastercode_03 = c(3039617L, 3039617L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L, 3039617L), mastercode_04 = c(3000470L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L, 3000470L), mastercode_05 = c(3039123L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L, 3039123L), mastercode_06 = c(1000054L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L, 1000054L), mastercode_07 = 1000001:1000006, 
                  mastercode_08 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_09 = c(NA_integer_, 
                                                                                              NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
                                    ), mastercode_10 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                                         NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), mastercode_11 = c(NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                   NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
                                                         ), mastercode_12 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                                                              NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The following calls will respectively say:
Which column names of test2 exist in test1
The vector index number of which column names of test2 exist in test1
The data frame subset of test2 whose column names exist in test1

```
names(test2) %in% names(test1)
which(names(test2) %in% names(test1))
test2[,names(test2) %in% names(test1)]
```